# How to convert, in Scala, an Array[VertexIds] to a Map?

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

In Scala, I have a an array of VertexIds

```
v: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId] = Array(-2634311911308936962, 2326575714372975825, ...)
```

that i want to convert to a map where

```
Map(-2634311911308936962 -> 0,
    2326575714372975825  -> 1,
    ...
)
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: v.zipWithIndex.toMap make some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

won't be sorted though